# How to fix time interval on automatic slideshow when manual controls are used

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I need help with this slideshow. I want it to be automatic and to be able to be controlled manually aswell. so far its working fine in the automatic part. However when I click the manual controls it takes me to a wrong slide and the time interval for the next 1 or 2 slides is messed up. If anyone has a solution to this then please help.

I have tried to change slideIndex to 0 but that takes me to the 1st slide istead of the next slide.

```js
  
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 

      } 
  
        slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  
      }
 
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 10 seconds
    }
```

```css
   
     * {box-sizing: border-box;}
      body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
    .mySlides {display: none;}
    img {vertical-align: middle;}

    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }

    /* Caption text */
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }

    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }

    @keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4} 
      to {opacity: 1}
    }

    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .text {font-size: 11px}
    }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -22px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
     }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
    */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
```

```html
    <h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
    <p>Change image every 10 seconds:</p>

    <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
```

I expect the interval to be 10 seconds but it turns out to be a couple seconds instead. Also i expect the next / previous slide when buttons are clicked and they aren't working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the fact that you are setting a timeout for your slideshow automatically and when you press the next or previous buttons your old timeouts do not cancel so now you have switched slides, the old timeout will still trigger and then you've also set a new one so it will trigger as well all way within the range of time that you would like.

Instead of creating a timeout for each button click i would suggest using intervals and keeping track of it outside any functions.

When the user presses a forward or back button cancel that interval and create a new one so that you don't run into the issue you are having now where you basically have like 10 loops spamming your carousel at the same time.

JAVASCRIPT

```
let slideIndex = 0;
const slideTime = 5000;
let slideInterval = setInterval(() => changeSlide(true), slideTime);

function jumpSlide(forward) {
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
  changeSlide(forward)
  slideInterval = setInterval(() => changeSlide(true), slideTime);
}

function changeSlide(forward) {
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  slides[slideIndex].classList.remove('active');
  if (forward) {
   if (slideIndex + 1 > slides.length - 1) {
    slides[0].classList.add('active');
    slideIndex = 0;
  } else {
    slides[slideIndex + 1].classList.add('active');
    slideIndex ++;
  } 
  } else {
    if (slideIndex - 1 < 0) {
    slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('active');
    slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
  } else {
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
    slideIndex --;
  }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='slide-container'>
<div class='slide active'></div>
<div class='slide'></div>
<div class='slide'></div>
</div>
<button onclick='jumpSlide(false)'>last slide</button>
<button onclick='jumpSlide(true)'>next slide</button>
```

CSS

```
.slide-container{
  display: flex;
}
.slide {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much that helped a lot. Is there a way to make only the active image visible on the screen at one time?

Comment: Feel free to hit that up vote button on the answer :).
You could do that a few ways. Here's a CodePen with the code above but with the feature you requested. This is just one way to do it.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PraKwK

Comment: My lord, you saved the day!